# Outh 2.0 refresh token issue

Tags: php, session, oauth-2.0, refresh, google-oauth

Working with Oauth 2.0, 
so I got the Ouath files from this site http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/11/login-with-google-api-php, everything is working fine for about an hour, we even are forcing the login to a specific domain.

Issue is that after 1 hour of being logged in everything turns white, the page doesn't load anything, I am assuming the refresh_token is not working and the session expired. In order to get access to the site again we need to add ?rest=1 to the end of the url to log us out.

Does anyone know what is causing this issue and how to fix it?

Would like to either let the user continue to be logged in after an hour, or ask log them out and get them to log back in to get access to the site.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($gClient->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    echo 'Access Token Expired'; // Debug
    $gClient->authenticate();
    $newAccessToken = json_decode($gClient->getAccessToken());
    $gClient->refreshToken($newAccessToken->refresh_token);
}
```

Comment: Where do we add this? Also, we added a hosted domain, and only added hd=...com in one location, do we need to added it in other locations system the problem is with the refresh token?